# Comparing cells to cells, when all the cells in the same column is equal, delete the whole column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a real hard time putting my logic into excel vba code.
My logic: Comparing cells to cells, if cell A > cell B then continue to loop to the next column. When all the cell from the same column have the same value, then delete the whole column.

```
Sub deletecol()
    Dim LastCol As Range, LastRow As Range, rRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ActiveSheet

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            For j = 1 To LastCol
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                    Column(j).EntireColumn.Delete
                Else
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value > ActiveSheet.Cells(i,j).Value Then [this is the part that I'm stuck]
                
            Next j
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are currently doing is just comparing the cell objects. If you want the values, you must specifically ask for the value.

`ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value > ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value`

As for using the above as another condition, you might want to look into the Elseif keyword.

Consider the following code

```vb
If Range("a2").Value > 0 Then
    Range("b2").Value = "Positive"
ElseIf Range("a2").Value < 0 Then
    Range("b2").Value = "Negative"
End If
```

This page does a pretty decent job at explaining conditional controls in VBA
https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/else-if-statement

Comment: Ok, do u have any idea on how to do on the Else part?

Comment: I edited the answer. Hopefully, that should answer the question :)